BigQuery not recognizing columns? - Google Data analytics course questions
I am in the Google Data analytics course, and in this particular lesson we were instructed to download some data about avocados from Kaggle, upload it into sample bigquery, and do some BASIC addition using query commands. I seem to be encountering a cascade of issues that I'm not able to circumvent, including:

Bigquery not recognizing the columns im trying to call in the select statement
Not recognizing the addition operator
It keeps expecting the statement to have ended even though I'm including a bunch of commas.

The issues go as follows: I enter/copy/paste this into bigquery:
SELECT
    Date,
    Region,
    Small_Bags,
    Large_Bags,
    XLarge_Bags,
    Total_Bags,
    Small_Bags + Large_Bags + XLarge_Bags AS Total_Bags_Calc
FROM your-project.avocado_data.avocado_prices

When this data is entered, the following error is returned:

"Unrecognized name: Small_Bags; Did you mean Small Bags? at [4:9]"
**
Fine. After removing the underscores, the code looks as follows:**

SELECT
    Date,
    Region,
    Small Bags,
    Large Bags,
    XLarge Bags,
    Total Bags,
    Small Bags + Large Bags + XLarge Bags AS Total_Bags_Calc
FROM `sample-bigquery-421913.avocado_data.avocado_prices`

but, the following error is returned:

"Syntax error: Expected end of input but got "+" at [8:20]"

After removing the calculation the code looks as follows:
SELECT
    Date,
    Region,
    Small Bags,
    Large Bags,
    XLarge Bags,
    Total Bags,
    
FROM `sample-bigquery-421913.avocado_data.avocado_prices`

and returns the following error:

Unrecognized name: Small at [4:9]

After which it proceeds to tell me that it CANNOT recognize the names of ANY of the columns that I am trying to call inside this query. This is a BASIC mathematical query and i KNOW THAT. but WHY wont it let me do BASIC ADDITION. What am I doing WRONG I've been staring at this query for the last two days and I'm tearing my hear out over here.

have you tried adding square brackets around the column names? Sql and bigQuery doesnt like Small bags, but will often accept [Small Bags]

Your column names cannot have spaces in them when you are using a SELECT query, but if you enclose these columns in backticks then your query will look like:
SELECT 
Date, 
Region, 
`Small Bags`, 
`Large Bags`, 
`XLarge Bags`, 
`Total Bags`, 
`Small Bags` + `Large Bags` + `XLarge Bags` AS Total_Bags_Calc 
FROM your-project.avocado_data.avocado_prices

this should solve your error. As you aren't in control of the source table and names of the column, you could then avoid this problem in future by renaming the columns in your results set as follows:
SELECT 
Date,
Region,
`Small Bags` AS small_bags,
`Large Bags` AS large_bags,
`XLarge Bags` AS xlarge_bags,
`Total Bags` AS total_bags,
`Small Bags` + `Large Bags` + `XLarge Bags` AS Total_Bags_Calc
FROM your-project.avocado_data.avocado_prices

Also, to make sure the values of these columns are numeric when you are trying to add them together, you can explicitly cast the values in your query as follows:
SELECT 
CAST(Date AS DATE) AS date,
Region AS region,
CAST(`Small Bags` as INT64) AS small_bags,
CAST(`Large Bags` as INT64) AS large_bags,
CAST(`XLarge Bags` as INT64) AS xlarge_bags,
CAST(`Total Bags` as INT64) AS total_bags,
`Small Bags` + `Large Bags` + `XLarge Bags` AS Total_Bags_Calc
FROM your-project.avocado_data.avocado_prices


Google has more information on how to handle spaces in column names here - https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Data-Analytics/Unable-to-rename-BigQuery-Column-with-SQL-data-definition/m-p/716737/highlight/true#:~:text=BigQuery%20Field%20Naming%20Restrictions%3A%20Field,help%20BigQuery%20interpret%20them%20correctly.
